# spring data flow basic sample issue

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm a beginner on spring cloud data flow and i started on the simple tutorial: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started

But at step "5. Deploying Streams" when deploying the stream i cannot see the out put in the console.

And while discovering the app i realy don't know where to start to find the problem.

So I know that the event is sent to rabbitMq because in the rabbitMq dashboard i can see it in the messages rates.
When i deployed the stream the server logs the local path of logs but nothing is logged here....

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the issue. 
Currently the server creates a log file for each application deployed. And obviously was looking at the bad one

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the log-location's from Dashboard (via `Runtime` tab). See the [quick-start](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#quick-start) guide for more details.